# Change size of figure in MATLAB to use them in LaTeX

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure, figure

I have generated several plots in MATLAB and I haven't set the ( width or height) to any of them. I save them as pdf to place them in LaTeX but each figure appear with different size. I can change each figure size in LaTeX but I wonder if there is an easy way in MATLAB to get same size for all figures.

1. Can I reset the figure size after generating in MATLAB or I have to regenerate each figure with specific  size?
2. What is the best way to export figures in MATLAB to use them in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

Exporting figures from MATLAB to LaTeX is best done via [.eps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript)  or directly to PDF. MATLAB's [`saveas()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) functionality supports both. The benefit of these file-types is that thy are *vector files*, meaning, loosely, that coordinates of corners in the lines are saved, as opposed to a bunch of fixed pixels such as with PNG or JPG figures. Using then these figures in LaTeX gives infinite scalability (theoretically, usefulness of highly-zoomed figures may vary).

If you need different *aspect ratios*, i.e. one figure taller than broad, the other broader than tall, You'd have to set the proper aspect ratio for each figure independently, then save using one of the aforementioned vector file types.

One of the best ways to export pretty figures is the [`export_fig()`](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig) functionality written by Oliver Woodford and currently maintained by Yair Altman and freely available on the FileExchange.

---

Answering your first question: yes you can resize figures after generating them. Either by hand (change the window size), or programatically: you can make a figure handle (`h=figure();`, where `h` is your handle), which has several options to control figure size; `h.position` being the most prominent: `[upper-left, lower-left, upper-right, lower-right]` being its content in terms of corner coordinates. Changing those changes the figure size.

Comment: Is there a way to rest size from figure properties ?

Comment: @Adam define "rest size"